# Converting mySQL's KEY to PgSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm converting some mySQL code to pgSQL and I've run into this problem

mysql code : "KEY ug_main_grp_id (ug_main_grp_id)"

What would be the equivalent in PgSQL. First I thought I could just use CREATE INDEX in pgSQL, but that's really not appropriate because KEY is not an index :P

Comment: Ok so  KEY is an INDEX tnx for clearing that up. But if a mysql query contains something like 

  PRIMARY KEY  (sess_id),
  KEY sess_id (sess_id),
  KEY start_time (start_time),
  KEY remote_ip (remote_ip)

I cant have more then one primary, so should I just create the others are unique indexes or is there a better solution

Answer (score 2):

`KEY` *is* an index, if that's the exact syntax you're porting.

Answer (score 2):

Given your example: `KEY ug_main_grp_id (ug_main_grp_id)`

you would add right after the `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE INDEX ug_main_grp_id ON TheTableName ( ug_main_grp_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PRIMARY KEY (ug_main_grp_id)
```

Comment: And yes, it is implemented as an index, as most DBMSes do, but that is, as the statement indicates, an implementation detail....

Comment: Thanks. I added a comment above, what if I have multiple Keys and I already have a PKey

Answer (score 0):

If they key is unique, just use *UNIQUE* as in:

```
mycolumn int NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

but if it's a non-unique one, you need to use the *CREATE INDEX* command.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special in pgsql if you have multiple indexes, it'll figure out which ones to use for a given query automatically.